# SpringMVC: How to prevent client directly visit a JSP view?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using SpringMVC to make a simple web app.

My controller request mapping is like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "index.html")
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("type", "index");
    return "index";
}
```

When I use visit the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8012/MyCloud/index.html
```

Things work fine and I can see the properly rendered `/views/index.jsp`.

But if I `directly` visit the `views/index.jsp` file with the following URL, the URL is indeed `visitable`. And an ugly 500 server error because apparently, there's no attribute named `"type"` been set so `NullReferenceException` is thrown.

```
http://localhost:8012/MyCloud/views/index.jsp
```

By mapping request to `*.html` URL, I want to trick my customer into believing they are visiting plain HTML page. But if they `somehow` managed to know my JSP view locations and visit them `directly`, they will see ugly errors.

Can I prevent this?

Shall I use an error page?

Comment: put the jsps under web-inf and they can't be accessed directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servlet containers won't serve any content in WEB-INF. By putting your JSPs there, you prevent anyone from directly accessing a JSP by navigating to it in the browser by name.

so move all your JSPs to the WEB-INF folder, and user will not be able to directly access the urls, while the controller code will be able to render the UI properly with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can cofigure a error page in web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <location>/general-error.html</location>
</error-page>
```